# Request on a copied table is faster than on original table, why?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

Here is a very simple request :

```sql
    select
         ftljh."ID_TRAIN",
         ftljh."ID_JOUR",
         ftljh."ID_LEG",
         2 as "CMPT",
         ftljh."JX",
         ftljh."CAPA",
         ftljh."OFFRE",
         ftljh."RES",
         ftljh."CC_OUV"
    from public."F_TDLJ_HIST_2" ftljh
    where "ID_JOUR" between 4620 and 4650
    and "JX" between -92 and 1
    and "ID_TRAIN" in (10625,11891,11242,735,13674,14697,14852,15917)
```

I ran it, and got a response time of ~1min44s. You can find the whole EXPLAIN ANALYZE here : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/g4ebc5g851h4d71b

My table `public."F_TDLJ_HIST_2"` is partitioned, but I ensured my request only select from one of those partitions.

I then copied this exact requested partition subtable to another schema, using CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ... and INSERT INTO ... (SELECT * FROM my_partition_subtable).

```sql
    select
         ftljh."ID_TRAIN",
         ftljh."ID_JOUR",
         ftljh."ID_LEG",
         2 as "CMPT",
         ftljh."JX",
         ftljh."CAPA",
         ftljh."OFFRE",
         ftljh."RES",
         ftljh."CC_OUV"
    from experiment."F_TDLJ_HIST_2" ftljh
    where "ID_JOUR" between 4620 and 4650
    and "JX" between -92 and 1
    and "ID_TRAIN" in (10625,11891,11242,735,13674,14697,14852,15917)
```

returned all my data in 11s!. The EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the request made against the copied table can be found here: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/89geefh65e15df9d

I can't find a reason for this difference. I tried a VACUUM, a VACUUM FULL, restoring indexes, and I'm a bit out of ideas.

EDIT : My table is partitionned on ID_JOUR. One subtable contains 90 ID_JOUR (90 days). It contains ~80M rows, and weights ~50GB. My requests are tailored to only request from one subtable. The experiment."F_TDLJ_HIST_2" contains exactly the data stored in the partitionned table requested from public."F_TDLJ_HIST_2" (so experiment.F_TDLJ_HIST_2 = partitionschema."F_TDLJ_HIST_2_p4590"). The execution plan against the copied table is the second explain.dalibo link.

SECOND EDIT : I found a solution that made my request almost instant. I used the CLUSTER USING command to physically reorganize my data, which has made my query 100x faster. What mechanism could explain such an improvement ?

To be precise, I created an index using btree("ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR") and then used this index to cluster my table.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Interesting question, but the it is possibly missing a couple of details. What is your table partitioned on? Is it `ID_TRAIN`? How may records does the table contain? How may records in the partition? What is the execution plan of the statement run against the "copied table"? Could you click on [edit] and add these details to your question? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my post to include the missing details !

Comment: Perhaps it's the index bloat?

Comment: Is this reproducible if you switch back and forth several times?  It looks to me like the faster query found most of its needed data already in memory (mostly the filesystem cache).  Turn on track_io_timing to get more clarity there.

Comment: Yes it was reproducible. I vary the perimeter I select every time.

Comment: What is the index bloat ?

Comment: Your first query returns 87373 rows, while your second query returns only 34968 rows. `CLUSTER` speeds up the index scan, because the index scan has to read far less pages to get all the rows. If you use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, you will see the difference.